# Prevent data corruption in azure mapping data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

We're ingesting thousands of XML files, one example of this being a shipment event recon.

In the data flow we're splitting up the contents of the file to be sinked to various tables, e.g.

- Order
- Delivery
- Loading
- Vehicle

The basic structure of the XML file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<payload>
  <header>
    ...
  </header>
  <deliveries>
    ...
  </deliveries>
  <loadings>
    ...
  </loadings>
  <vehicles>
    ...
  </vehicles>
</payload>
```

When we designed the tables we configured certain fields to require information which is where the problem came in.

During tests we found a scenario where DF started writing information to the tables (deliveries and vehicles) but then failed on the loadings table, due to a "can't insert null into..." exception, which caused the pipeline to fail/stop.

Now we have a bunch of orphaned records.

My first assumption was that DF would handle the entire data flow as a transaction, meaning if any part of the file ingestion fails, it shouldn't write any records to any of the tables. Not the case apparently.

Second assumption was that it would be easy to figure out which file caused the failure so that we could inspect the data. Again, not so.

Questions:

1. How do we prevent this sort of data corruption from happening
2. How do we find the file that caused the issue

We've attempted to configure the Error tab in the data flow sink transformation, but it never writes anything to the container even though we do have all the relevant permissions correctly configured.